# Mobx observable fields not updating in observer( UI ) when used with React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-react-lite

I'm creating a simple React app with react-hooks using a mobx store. The packages I'm using here is mobx and mobx-react-lite.
**When I click on the Add/Multiply buttons, nothing happens. The updated count value is not reflecting.
Am I missing something to add somewhere, which we need to support mobx?**
This is how the code is structured:

**App.tsx =>**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        Math
      </header>
      <hr />
      <Multiplier />
      <Adder />
      <Square />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Multiplier.tsx =>**

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import { useCounterStore } from "../storeProvider/RootStoreProvider";

function Multiplier(){
    const store = useCounterStore();
    return(
        <div>
            <div>Count after multiplying by 5: {store.count}</div>
            <button onClick={() => store.multiplyByFive()}>Multiply</button>
        </div>
        
    )
}

export default observer(Multiplier);
```

**Adder.tsx =>**

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import { useCounterStore } from "../storeProvider/RootStoreProvider";

function Adder(){
    const store = useCounterStore();
    return(
        <div>
            <div>Count after addition by 5: {store.count}</div>
            <button onClick={() => store.addByFive()}>Add</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default observer(Adder);
```

**Square.tsx =>**

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import { useCounterStore } from "../storeProvider/RootStoreProvider";

function Square(){
    const store = useCounterStore();
    return(
        <div>Count square : {store.Squared}</div>
    )
}

export default observer(Square);
```

**The useCounterStore is exported from this file:**

```
import { createContext, ReactNode, useContext } from "react";
import { RootStore } from "../store/Root";

let store: RootStore;
const RootStoreContext = createContext<RootStore | undefined>(undefined);

export function useRootStore() {
    const context = useContext(RootStoreContext);
    if (context === undefined) {
        throw new Error("useRootStore must be used within RootStoreProvider");
    }

    return context;
}

export function useCounterStore() {
    const { CounterStore } = useRootStore();
    return CounterStore;
}

export function RootStoreProvider({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
    const root = store ?? new RootStore();

    return <RootStoreContext.Provider value={root}>{children}</RootStoreContext.Provider>
}
```

**This same file is exporting RootStoreProvider which is used in the index.tsx file =>**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <RootStoreProvider>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </RootStoreProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results
reportWebVitals();
```

**Edit1 (RootStore.ts):**

```
import { Counter } from "./Counter";

export class RootStore{
    public CounterStore:Counter;

    constructor(){
        this.CounterStore = new Counter();
    }
}
```

**Edit2 : CounterStore =>**

```
import { action, computed, observable } from "mobx";

export class Counter{
    @observable count = 0;

    @action multiplyByFive(){
        this.count = this.count * 5;
    }

    @action addByFive(){
        this.count = this.count + 5;
    }

    @computed get Squared(){
        return this.count * this.count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your RootStore code? It is the most important part actually

Comment: Updated with Root store

Comment: @Danila That worked. 
makeObservable was the trick. Thanks.